# arm package in R: warning message Warning message: In is.na(thedata) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Tags: r, arm, warnings, na

I am running a glmer (see below) using the lme4 package in R. The initial model runs fine with no warning messages.

```
globalMat.model <- glmer(hatched~poly(MaternalAge,degree=2,raw=T)+Clutchnumber
                         +ClutchSize +maternalweight+ (1|PairID) + 
                         (1|Year),data=crexMat, family=binomial)
summary(globalMat.model)
```

Following this I am using the arm package to standardise my global model.

```
stdz.modelMAT<-standardize(globalMat.model, unchanged = NULL, 
                            standardize.y=FALSE, binary.inputs = "center")
summary(stdz.modelMAT)
```

the functions runs but i get the following warning

```
Warning message:
In is.na(thedata) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

I can't see why this would be. There are no NA's in the data set.

Has anyone else had this problem or have any ideas about how to solve it?

Thanks